# How to find element and click by XPath in selenium using google colab cell?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-colaboratory

I installed selenium webdriver on google colab and opened https://imgbb.com/ website successfully using this commands:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "https://imgbb.com/" 
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver", options=options)

driver.get(url)
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from IPython.display import HTML

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1024,768")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
```

```
driver.get("https://imgbb.com/")
```

```
HTML("""<img src="data:image/png;base64,{0}">""".format(driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()))
```

**Now i want to click on Start uploading button in that webpage but when i use following command i get error:**

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(@class,'btn btn-big')])[1]")).click();`

**i get this error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-65-a8a528fd0b6b> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(@class,'btn btn-big')])[1]")).click();

AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'findElement'
```

**Even i run this command:**

`driver.find_Element_By_xpath("(//a[contains(@class,'btn btn-big')])[1]")).click();`

**but i get this error:**

```
  File "<ipython-input-66-a07f53a84f04>", line 1
    driver.find_Element_By_xpath("(//a[contains(@class,'btn btn-big')])[1]")).click();
                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: unmatched ')'
```

**How can i fix this problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//a[contains(@class,'btn btn-big')])[1]").click()
```

Imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

And to ensure you are using correct method of `driver` instance, you can run the below code:

```
print(dir(driver))
```

This will print all the valid methods for `driver` instance, something like below

```
['__abstractmethods__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__eq__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_abc_impl', '_authenticator_id', '_file_detector', '_get_cdp_details', '_is_remote', '_mobile', '_shadowroot_cls', '_switch_to', '_unwrap_value', '_web_element_cls', '_wrap_value', 'add_cookie', 'add_credential', 'add_virtual_authenticator', 'application_cache', 'back', 'bidi_connection', 'capabilities', 'caps', 'close', 'command_executor', 'create_options', 'create_web_element', 'current_url', 'current_window_handle', 'delete_all_cookies', 'delete_cookie', 'delete_network_conditions', 'desired_capabilities', 'error_handler', 'execute', 'execute_async_script', 'execute_cdp_cmd', 'execute_script', 'file_detector', 'file_detector_context', 'find_element', 'find_elements', 'forward', 'fullscreen_window', 'get', 'get_cookie', 'get_cookies', 'get_credentials', 'get_issue_message', 'get_log', 'get_network_conditions', 'get_pinned_scripts', 'get_screenshot_as_base64', 'get_screenshot_as_file', 'get_screenshot_as_png', 'get_sinks', 'get_window_position', 'get_window_rect', 'get_window_size', 'implicitly_wait', 'launch_app', 'log_types', 'maximize_window', 'minimize_window', 'mobile', 'name', 'orientation', 'page_source', 'pin_script', 'pinned_scripts', 'port', 'print_page', 'quit', 'refresh', 'remove_all_credentials', 'remove_credential', 'remove_virtual_authenticator', 'save_screenshot', 'service', 'session_id', 'set_network_conditions', 'set_page_load_timeout', 'set_permissions', 'set_script_timeout', 'set_sink_to_use', 'set_user_verified', 'set_window_position', 'set_window_rect', 'set_window_size', 'start_client', 'start_desktop_mirroring', 'start_session', 'start_tab_mirroring', 'stop_casting', 'stop_client', 'switch_to', 'timeouts', 'title', 'unpin', 'vendor_prefix', 'virtual_authenticator_id', 'window_handles']
```

Comment: i tried and get this error this time: `NameError: name 'By' is not defined`

Comment: Check the updated answer, add the required imports

Comment: I tried again this two commands and worked for me but i don't know why when i get screenshot no changes will be made to the opened website! `HTML("""<img src="data:image/png;base64,{0}">""".format(driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()))` When I click on the upload button on that website, a menu should open to select the file for uploading!

Comment: Looks like the issue reported in this question is resolved. If yes, accept this answer. About the issue in your comment above, its a new issue, if you need help from a wider community experts, create a new question specifying the exact error and share the code and error trace.